# What is different between ApiAuthorizationDbContext and IdentityDbContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

What is different between `ApiAuthorizationDbContext<TUser>` and `IdentityDbContext<TUser>` in a Web API project?

DbContext can inherit those but don't know what is different between those

(I'm using .NET 6.0 and Entity Framework Core for Web API project)

Comment: Hi @behroozbc, any update?

Comment: Hi @Rena thanks for keep tracking this question, soon I will check it

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src%2FIdentity%2FApiAuthorization.IdentityServer%2Fsrc%2FData%2FApiAuthorizationDbContext.cs), or in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.apiauthorization.identityserver.apiauthorizationdbcontext-1?view=aspnetcore-6.0), ApiAuthorizationDbContext inherits from
IdentityDbContext and it also implements IPersistedGrantDbContext which
is responsible for storing consent, authorization codes, refresh tokens, and reference tokens.

Comment: The source code moved to /dotnet/aspnetcore a few versions ago https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src%2FIdentity%2FApiAuthorization.IdentityServer%2Fsrc%2FData%2FApiAuthorizationDbContext.cs

Answer (score 0):

Except for what @gbede said about the `ApiAuthorizationDbContext<TUser>` usage, `ApiAuthorizationDbContext<TUser>` force `TUser` to extends `IdentityUser` instead of `IdentityUser<TKey>`. This means it is impossible to use Identity Server on application with `ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>`(or anything different from `IdentityUser<string>`).

`IdentityDbContext` can work with different `IdentityUser<TKey>`, you can customize your model like:

```
public class AppUser:IdentityUser<Guid>
{
    //add any additional properties
}
```

Then use the DbContext like:

```
public class MvcProjContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser,IdentityRole<Guid>,Guid>
{
    public MvcProjContext (DbContextOptions<MvcProjContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```